# Font-size that expands when you resize the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I make my font in HTML such that when I expand the window, the size of the text expands also. Sort of like setting a percentage for the text that will take on a percentage of the size of the box it is in.

Here is an illustration of what I would like to happen:

```
#box #text {
   font-size: 50%;
}
```

Now lets say `#box` is 200px, `#text` should be 100px.
Obviously I can't just put a fix width for `#text` because in the site `#box` will be a dynamic width.

Comment: As an ID is unique, there's no need to put #text besides #box in your css declaration.  Just write #text as no other element is supposed to get this ID

Comment: Okay, I understand that. I was just doing it like that to illustrate that `#text` was inside `#box`

Comment: @ecchymose: And, what if I use one css file for many html pages?

Comment: Then you're right I think!  If you can have #text inside #box in page A, but #text inside #box2 in page B, I guess you can be specific and declare "#box #text" on one line and "#box2 #text" after.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do it in jquery.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#box #text').css('font-size',($(window).width()*0.5)+'px');
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the `vh` (viewport height), `vw` (viewport width), and/or `vm` (viewport minimum (smallest of the dimensions)) units in browsers that fully support CSS3, and for other browsers listen for `resize` and JavaScript such as in Razor Storm's answer.

Comment: I didn't know about this vh vw vm stuff. Can you provide an example? it looks cool! :)

Comment: `100vw` is the width of the viewport; `200vw` is double of the width of the viewport. The rest should be self-explanatory. You'd likely want to use the `vm` unit since it uses the lesser of the two dimensions.

Comment: That's awesome! Does css3 have any more of these dynamic constants?

Comment: This is really cool, does this work with the height/width of the containing box. Reffering back to my question lets say `#box` is dynamically changed to be bigger or smaller will `#text` change with box. (Perhaps if `#box` has absolute positioning like with regards to `left` and `top` etc.)

Answer (score 1):

In browsers that support it, you can use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Media_queries#width) to change your layout depending on the width of the window.

Comment: Good idea but that won't allow me to dynamically control the size of the fonts depending on the window size.

Comment: @Chaim Chaikin You can use any CSS inside the media query block, so you can change the background colour or the list style image should you so want...

Comment: Yes, I understand, however the value of `font-size` can not be dynamically related to the size of the viewing window (or `#box` my case). This is particularly necessary to me as the user can resize the window however he/she wants and I want the `font-size` of `#text` to be adjusted exactly accordingly.