# Css font-size in % not reducing when we reduce the browser window size

Tags: html, css

**CSS**

```
#header
{
    width:90%;    
}

#bakeryintro
{
    width:40%;    
}

.bakeryintro1
{    
    font-size:350%;        
}

.bakeryintro2
{ 
    font-size:200%;
}
```

**Makup**

```
<div id="header">
        <div id="bakeryintro" class="editable draggable resizable text header">
            <span class="bakeryintro1">The Bakery</span><br />
            <span class="bakeryintro2">it`s all aboout the bread.</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

When i will reduce the size of browser the size of `#header and #bakeryinro` will reduced but the font-size in `#bakeryintro` remains as it is, Pls tell me the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Font-size that expands when you resize the window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207075/font-size-that-expands-when-you-resize-the-window)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you talking about this [prototype](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/2tQ5T/1/) ?

if you are, this is css only prototype-proof:

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; }
body { font-size: 1em;}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
    html { font-size: 70%; }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    html { font-size: 80%; }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
    html { font-size: 120%; }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    html { font-size: 200%; }
}
```

**Update:**
In comments @dystroy asked about smoothness of my method and neccessity to write 1200 rules for provide to simulate javascript way, but I thought about the thousands of rules, and found another way is to write a small number of rules for each integer value of the font size. The method has a right to exist, because browsers poorly supporting non-integer values ​​for the property `font-size`, that's why the 1200 rules for changing the font from 12 to 16 are not neccessable, because browser can realize only 5 (12, 13, 14, 15, 16):

```
/* for smoothness on the edges of the rules
   when font-size is changing */
.example { transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  }

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .example { font-size: 12px; }
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
    .example { font-size: 13px; }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .example { font-size: 14px; }
}

@media (min-width: 1300px) {
    .example { font-size: 15px; }
}

@media (min-width: 1400px) {
    .example { font-size: 16px; }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but this doesn't really make the font size proportional to the window, as you cannot reasonably make 1200 @media rules.

Comment: i don't think about font-size changing for every window width, 'cause of redundancy of this solution type. for some kind of smoothness you can add `transition property`

Comment: @dystroy i updated my post with new look for smoothness of changes

Answer (score 8):

The css attribute "font-size" in percent gives the size of your font relatively to the standard font size, not relatively to your screen.

So there is no reason for the font to change size when the window size changes.

If you really need it, you can use javascript to change your font size :

```
$('.bakeryintro1').css('font-size', ($(window).width()*0.01)+'px');
```

Comment: so is there any alternative for this?

Comment: The only alternative I see is using javascript to set the font size computed using the screen width. See edited answer.

Comment: @matmuchrapna : I upvote your solution, I didn't think about it. But this doesn't enable a smooth size change.

Comment: @dystroy ` transition: all 0.3s ease-out` may be added